# A sufficient condition for finite *-rings!

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a unital *-ring. Assume that $R$ has finitely many projections.

Q. Can we conclude that $R$ is finite?!

$\bullet$ We say $R$ is finite if    $x^*x=1_R$ implies that $xx^*=1_R$.

$\bullet$ $p\in R$ is called a projection if $p=p^*=p^2$.

Comment: Yes, it is easy - for $x^*x=1$, every $x^n(x^*)^n$ is a projection, and if two of them are equal then multiplying both sides of that equality by $x^*$ from the left and by $x$ from the right several times we get $xx^*=1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I agree that you get $x^n (x^*)^n = 1$ for *some* $n$, but why does it follow that $n=1$?

Comment: @AlexM. just keep multiplying :)